# Understanding discontinuities of a sum of functions

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

I had this problem:

> Consider the function $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor +|1-x|$ on $-1\leq x\leq3$ where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer function (GIF). Find the number of points where $f(x)$ is discontinuous.

My teacher did it via the following steps:

1. GIF is discontinuous at integer points. So at $0,1,3$ it's discontinuous.
2. Found value of $f(x)$ at $x=0,1,2,3$.
3. Proved $F(x)$ discont. at $x=3$ by comparing with left-hand limit.
4. Proved $F(x)$ is continuous at $x=-1$ by comparing it with right-hand limit.
5. Concluded that $F(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0,1,2,3$.

Now my doubt is that mod function is always continuous. And if a function $f(x) = f_1+f_2$ in which any of $f_1$ or $f_2$ is discont. at a point the function $f(x)$ need not always be discont. at the same point. Then how he concluded that $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0,1,2$?

Answer (score 1):

Break the function $f(x)=[x]+|1-x|$ in the domain [-1,3] piecewise .
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} -x ;-1\leq x \leq 0 \\(1-x); 0< x\leq1\\2x;1< x\leq2\\2x+1; x\in(2,3]\end{cases} $$
Now check the LHL and RHL at 0,1,2, points.  You can find $LHL\ne RHL$ at all these 3 points.  Hence limit doesn't exist there , so discontinuity lies exactly at these points. Now are they alone points of discontinuity?  To examine this check the piesewise functions constructed in between the intervals , all of them are continuous in the respective intervals . So yes ! 0,1 and 2 are the only points of discontinuity of the given function.
(P.S. although my approach is not very much rigorous).